# Option clash xcolor in moderncv

Tags: color, moderncv, overleaf, option-clash

I am trying to color a hyperlink in my cv with a non-standard blue in overleaf. When I load xcolor package, it gives me the error

> LaTex Error: Option clash for package xcolor

Am I right in thinking that the moderncv package already loads xcolor by itself and therefore clashes? And if so, why does it not find colors from the reference (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colours_in_LaTeX#Reference_guide)?

Updated (working) MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.77]{geometry}

\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvstyle{classic}  


\name{John}{Doe}
\title{updated \today}                               
\address{Fantasialand}{}{}
\title{Tex MWE}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle


\section{}
\cvitem{1.}{\href{https://www.wikipedia.de/}{\color{Turquoise}{Go to Stackexchange}}}

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE you inlcuded does result in a different error message due to the `#` in the url.

Comment: Apart from that, `xcolor` does not define a color named `turquoise`, it only defines `Turquoise`.  To be able to use the latter color in the `moderncv` class, add `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}` or `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}`  before `\documentclass`, depending on which of the two `Turquoise`colors you want to use.

Comment: Thank you, changed the MWE above but it still does not work. Also tried to position `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` in different places and still did not work

Comment: @Papayapap: The color name is now missing a "u". You used `Turqoise` while, the color ns named `Turquoise`.

Comment: @leandriis, aah, indeed. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: You also can load the  `[dvipsnames]` option as an option of `\documentclass`.